# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function after updating webpack resolve.modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

To get absolute imports working with Typescript, I added `baseUrl` to my tsconfig and added `modules` to the `resolve` section of my webpack.config.js. It went from:

```
resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", ".jsx"]
  },
```

to

```
resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", ".jsx"],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main/resources/static/")
    ]
  },
```

once I did that, however, webpack was no longer resolving imports from `node_modules`, so I updated it to:

```
resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", ".jsx"],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main/resources/static/"),
      path.resolve("./node_modules")
    ]
  },
```

after that, I started getting the following exception in the console on the page I was working on:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js (index.ts:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js   @   index.ts:17
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:18
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:82
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:83
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was due to webpack resolving the wrong version of `immer` imported by redux toolkit. Under the root `node_modules` I see `immer` version 5 and embedded within `node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit` I see another `node_modules` with `immer` version 7 inside it. I found out that webpack was resolving the wrong version due to me adding the `modules` key under `resolve` in my webpack config. The default value for `modules`, [as stated in the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules), is `["node_modules"]`.  I had added the root path of my scripts to enable absolute imports and then included the *root* `node_modules` to enable regular external dependency imports, but I had prevented webpack from resolving imports using embedded `node_modules` directories by neglecting to include just `"node_modules"` in the `resolve.modules`. Ended up with this, which is working again:

```
  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", ".jsx"],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main/resources/static/"),
      "node_modules",
    ]
  },
```